# Overfull hbox in header

Tags: graphics, fancyhdr

I get an overfull hbox in a header within command for \rhead, which I didn't expect since it's right justified.  For some reason, removing the footer seems to fix it, yet removing the tikz package gives me an undefined control sequence.  Seems like I've done something wrong, but I cant pin it down. How do I fix this?

Here's the code with the guts stripped out.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=1.25in, headheight=1.02in, headsep=0.08in, bottom=0.85in, footskip=0.0in,
            left=0.75in, right=0.75in]{geometry} % showframe option handy for designing.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage[toc, page]{appendix}
%% \usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%% % Make the links blue, to follow the Web convention. Using xcolor syntax, internal links will be
%% % 70 % blue, the remainder black, and URLs 80 % blue (brighter)
\hypersetup{colorlinks, linkcolor={blue!70!black}, citecolor={blue!50!black}, urlcolor={blue!80!black}}


\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps}


% Give the subsubsections letters instead of numbers
\renewcommand \thesubsubsection {\thesubsection.\alph{subsubsection}}

% Use fancy headers and footers, and make the footer show the Subsection and Name %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{{\color{GreenYellow}%
\hrule width\headwidth height\headrulewidth \vskip-\headrulewidth}}

\renewcommand{\subsubsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsubsection.\ #1}}

%\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
%\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\rhead{\includegraphics[width=1.25in]{CDS}}

\lhead{Config Control--General Classification\\Config CONTROLLED}

\cfoot{\fancyplain{}{\begin{center}}
    \footnotesize{\rightmark}
    \begin{tabular}[c]{| p{1.1875in} | p{0.5625in} | p{3.3157in} | p{1.5in} |}
    \hline
    \centering \footnotesize{Document number} &  \centering \footnotesize{Issue} &  \centering \footnotesize{Config Control--General Classification} &
    \tabularnewline
    \centering JSGT XXXX & \centering 1 & \centering Config CONTROLLED &  \centering\small{Page {\thepage}}
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \tiny{\copyright{} \the\year{} Company name}
    \end{center}
}


\begin{document}
%
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
%
% Title page
\maketitle
\newpage
Some text....
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also, are boxes as in overfull and underfull boxes a latex concept or specific to graphicx?  I couldn't find anything about them in the graphicx documentation...

Comment: they are primitive TeX warnings from the underlying tex engine, not latex specific at all, certainly not graphicx specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overfull box is the foot not the head, it's simply too wide.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=1.25in, headheight=1.02in, headsep=0.08in, bottom=0.85in, footskip=0.0in,
            left=0.75in, right=0.75in]{geometry} % showframe option handy for designing.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage[toc, page]{appendix}
%% \usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%% % Make the links blue, to follow the Web convention. Using xcolor syntax, internal links will be
%% % 70 % blue, the remainder black, and URLs 80 % blue (brighter)
\hypersetup{colorlinks, linkcolor={blue!70!black}, citecolor={blue!50!black}, urlcolor={blue!80!black}}


\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps}

% Give the subsubsections letters instead of numbers
\renewcommand \thesubsubsection {\thesubsection.\alph{subsubsection}}

% Use fancy headers and footers, and make the footer show the Subsection and Name %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{{\color{GreenYellow}%
\hrule width\headwidth height\headrulewidth \vskip-\headrulewidth}}

\renewcommand{\subsubsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsubsection.\ #1}}

%\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
%\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\rhead{\includegraphics[width=1.25in]{example-image}}

\lhead{Config Control--General Classification\\Config CONTROLLED}

\cfoot{\fancyplain{}{\begin{center}}
    \footnotesize{\rightmark}
    \begin{tabular}[c]{| p{1in} | p{0.5in} | p{3.3in} | p{1.5in} |}
    \hline
    \centering \footnotesize{Document number} &  \centering \footnotesize{Issue} &  \centering \footnotesize{Config Control--General Classification} &
    \tabularnewline
    \centering JSGT XXXX & \centering 1 & \centering Config CONTROLLED &  \centering\small{Page {\thepage}}
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \tiny{\copyright{} \the\year{} Company name}
    \end{center}
}


\begin{document}
%
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
%
% Title page
\maketitle
\newpage
Some text....
\end{document}
```

Comment: So that i may learn to fish, in addition to eating the fish you've kindly given me, how could you tell that was the problem?

Comment: @Beachcomber well actually, given the MWE it was the only possible place, but if you uncomment the `\showbox` settings in your original the log file shows the box contents as `.......\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.......\OT1/pxr/m/n/8 D
.......\OT1/pxr/m/n/8 o
.......\OT1/pxr/m/n/8 c
.......\OT1/pxr/m/n/8 u
` which is clearly the footer text (read the last column vertically)  Where did you get the bad column widths from?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  I inherited that footer with its column widths from a colleague who didn't care to fix errors and warnings... In fairness, he's even more of a Latex newbie than me.  It seems as though each column is wider than it's set to be.

Comment: the widths are the widths for line breaking but each column has \tabcolsep padding either side, and the width of the vertical rules needs to be accounted for.